# CSS で数字を含めて縦書き表示を実現したい

Tags: css

Ankiという試験勉強アプリを使用し、表示をカスタマイズしようしています。
漢字の問題なので、縦書き、右上揃えにして、数字を縦中横にしたいです。
※現在は左揃え、中央寄せ、数字が横書きになってしまっています。

どのように変更したら綺麗に表示できますでしょうか。
教えてください！

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

アドバイスの通り、CSSをコピペしましたところ、このような表示になってしまいました。何を修正したらよいのでしょうか、初心者すぎてすみません。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

oririさん早速ありがとうございます。
ご提案通りにやってみたのですが、左寄せかつ、空白になってしまいました。
何がいけないのでしょうか。何度もすみません。。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

お返事ありがとうございます。現在このような状況です。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

アプリの問題画面をプレビューをすると、あとは、右揃えのみです。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ただ、CSSのwedthを100％にすると、すごく空間があいてしまうので、空欄％になってしまっております。

ひとつ前のものは「カードの表面が空白になっています」と表示され打ち込んだ問題がリンクされて表示されなかったため、表面、裏面は「フィールドを追加」から入れ込んでいます。

右揃えするには、どうしたらよいでしょうか。そもそもCSSがおかしいですよね？

Comment: 回答の「テンプレートの例」通りにテンプレートを用意してみては？
`style="font-family: arial; font-size: 20px;"` のような指定はテンプレートでなく CSSがよいでしょう。スニペットを使えば質問や回答で再現も可能なはずです(テンプレート全体を `<div class="card">`〜`</div>`で括る必要があるけど)

Comment: ありがとうございます、やってみたのですが、表示がおかしいです、私の書き方がいけないのでしょうか、、涙

Comment: 上にアップしてみました、、何度も申し訳ございません。

Comment: 表面のテンプレートの末尾に`</div>`を追記しても右寄せになりませんか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。仰っていただいた表面のテンプレートは実際には打ち込んだ問題がPCからリンクされず、カードの表面が空白になってしまったので、「フィールドを追加」から問題番号、解答など、入れ込みました。

Comment: この状態から右揃えにしたいですが…

Comment: ① 質問や回答で**スニペット使う**ならテンプレート全体を <div class="card">で, とコメントしたけど, テンプレートに対しては付けないほうがよいでしょう (アプリ側ですでに付けてるだろうから, 問題が出る可能性も)
② 右寄せは`width: 100%;`を指定 という回答付いてるので, 正しく `100%` と記述してみてください
③ たぶん分かりやすさのために `<span>`, `<upright>` のタグが使われてるのかもだけど, 共有デッキに上がってるデッキ見てると(漢字検定確認してみたけど), クラス名で指定することが多いようです (ここで言う `.card` のような名称)

Comment: ありがとうございます。①スニペットをつけていないと、問題が空白になってしまって表示されないのですが、どうしたらよいでしょうか・・（画像でアップしています）②は100と記述するととても広い空白が出てしまって、問題が見切れてしまいます。（画像でアップしています）
③そうなのですね、どうやったらよいでしょうか、
何から手を付けてよいか分からないです・・

Comment: まず試しに, 回答の通りに行って動作を確認してみるべきかと思います。一時的な回答用意しました (そのうち消します)

Answer (score 3):

縦書きにしたい半角数字を<span></span>で囲んでください。
囲った箇所にのみ`text-combine-upright`が適用されます。

縦書きの上寄せは`text-align: left;`を、右寄せは`width: 100%;`を指定することで実現できます。

**テンプレートの例**

```
(問題番号)<br/>
(学習のポイント)<br/>
(問題<span>1</span>) ←&lt;<upright>span</upright>で囲った&gt;<br/>
(問題2) ←&lt;spanで囲ってない&gt;
<hr id=answer>

{{裏面}}
```

**CSSの例**

```
.card {
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
}
div {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  width: 100%;
}
span {
  text-combine-upright: all;
  <!-- vertical-align: top; -->
  display: inline-block;
}
upright {
  text-orientation: upright;
}
```

**実行結果**

[image: 実行結果のスクリーンショット]

**参考資料**

- [【CSS】writing-modeで縦書きレイアウトの仕方とハマりポイント解説](https://miyattiblog.com/vertical-layout/#width_100)
- [CSS の縦書きで数字が横向きになってイライラしたら](https://qiita.com/otsuky/items/6bd14aaa47e64ba12fa2)

Comment: payaneco様　早速のお返事どうもありがとうございます！

Comment: CSSをコピペさせていただいて、表面のデザインの変更を試そう（数字をspanで区切る）と思ったら、右上揃えになっているのですが、一つ目と二つ目の文字がかなり離れてしまって、三つ目の文字が表示されていない事態になっております。

Comment: ここに画像が添付できなさそうなのですが、学習のポイント１と問題1が離れすぎてしまい問題2が表示されていないという状況です。

Comment: お返事ありがとうございます。まだ右揃えにできていない状況です。お分かりの方、教えてください。。